How to change the color of cursor in nvim
In my nvim, the text is being highlighted by the white line and a light blue block cursor.
I understand the way to change the cursor by modifying init.lua. However I couldn't fine the resource about the cursor line is highlighting the text.
Can you teach me how to change the highlight bar?
I can't see what I ma typing now.
I try to edit the init.lua
with vim.o.guicursor = 'n-v-c-sm-i-ci-ve:block,r-cr-o:hor20,a:blinkwait700-blinkoff400-blinkon250-Cursor/lCursor'.
But I am not even sure if the code is effecting on the setting.
I need the highlight bar to be more dark so I can see the text.
For additional information I am using Lazy.nvim for configuration.

you can modify the CursorLine highlight group in your init.lua:
vim.o.cursorline = true -- Ensure the cursorline is enabled
vim.cmd([[
  highlight CursorLine guibg=#1e1e2e guifg=NONE
]])


If you use Lazy.nvim try this.
In your settings init.lua
vim.cmd([[
  highlight CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=DarkGray guibg=#3c3c3c
]])

The highlight cursorline determines the appearance of the line under the cursor.
Your cursor settings (vim.o.guicursor) should be fine. Make sure the are priority in init.lua to have effect. Sometimes this works.
Another problem could be that other plugins/themes override Lazy.nvim
